# Is kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat supported on iPhoneOS?

Tags: iphone, audiounit

I am writing an iPhone app that records and plays audio simultaneously using the I/O audio unit as per [Apple's recommendations](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html#PLAYBACK-RECORD_AND_PLAY_BACK_AUDIO_AT_THE_SAME_TIME).

I want to apply some sound effects (reverb, etc) on the recorded audio before playing it back. For these effects to work well, I need the samples to be floating point numbers, rather than integers. It seems this should be possible, by creating an `AudioStreamBasicDescription` with `kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat` set on `mFormatFlags`. This is what my code looks like:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamDescription;

streamDescription.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
streamDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
streamDescription.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat;
streamDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 32;
streamDescription.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
streamDescription.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
streamDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
streamDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
streamDescription.mReserved = 0;

OSStatus status;

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &streamDescription, sizeof(streamDescription));
if (status != noErr)
  fprintf(stderr, "AudioUnitSetProperty (kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input) returned status %ld\n", status);

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &streamDescription, sizeof(streamDescription));
if (status != noErr)
  fprintf(stderr, "AudioUnitSetProperty (kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output) returned status %ld\n", status);
```

However, when I run this (on an iPhone 3GS running iPhoneOS 3.1.3), I get this:

```
AudioUnitSetProperty (kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input) returned error -10868
AudioUnitSetProperty (kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output) returned error -10868
```

(-10868 is the value of `kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported`)

I didn't find anything of value in Apple's documentation, apart from a [*recommendation*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html#PLAYBACK-CHOOSE_THE_BEST_AUDIO_FORMATS_IN_IPHONE_OS) to stick to 16 bit little-endian integers. However, the [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) example project contains at least some support code related to `kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat`.

So, is my stream description incorrect, or is `kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat` simply not supported on iPhoneOS?

Answer (score 4):

It's not supported, as far as I know.  You *can* pretty easily convert to floats, though using AudioConverter.  I do this conversion (both ways) in real time to use the Accelerate framework with iOS audio.  (note: this code is copied and pasted from more modular code, so there may be some minor typos)

First, you'll need the AudioStreamBasicDescription from the input.  Say

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription aBasicDescription = {0};
aBasicDescription.mSampleRate       = self.samplerate;
aBasicDescription.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
aBasicDescription.mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger |     kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
aBasicDescription.mFramesPerPacket          = 1;
aBasicDescription.mChannelsPerFrame     = 1;
aBasicDescription.mBitsPerChannel       = 8 * sizeof(SInt16);
aBasicDescription.mBytesPerPacket       = sizeof(SInt16) * aBasicDescription.mFramesPerPacket;
aBasicDescription.mBytesPerFrame        = sizeof(SInt16) * aBasicDescription.mChannelsPerFrame
```

Then, generate a corresponding AudioStreamBasicDescription for float.

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription floatDesc = {0};
floatDesc.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;      
floatDesc.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
floatDesc.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * sizeof(float);
floatDesc.mFramesPerPacket = 1;                                          
floatDesc.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;           
floatDesc.mBytesPerPacket = sizeof(float) * floatDesc.mFramesPerPacket;                                                                            
floatDesc.mBytesPerFrame = sizeof(float) * floatDesc.mChannelsPerFrame;                                                                                   
floatDesc.mSampleRate = [controller samplerate];
```

Make some buffers.

```
UInt32 intSize = inNumberFrames * sizeof(SInt16);
UInt32 floatSize = inNumberFrames * sizeof(float);
float *dataBuffer = (float *)calloc(numberOfAudioFramesIn, sizeof(float));
```

Then convert.  (ioData is your AudioBufferList containing the int audio)

```
AudioConverterRef converter;
OSStatus err = noErr;
err = AudioConverterNew(&aBasicDescription, &floatDesct, &converter);
//check for error here in "real" code
err = AudioConverterConvertBuffer(converter, intSize, ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, &floatSize, dataBuffer);
//check for error here in "real" code
//do stuff to dataBuffer, which now contains floats
//convert the floats back by running the conversion the other way
```

Comment: Since iOS 9 (at least), the internal (cannot use the term canonical, since it is deprecated! :-) )  format on iOS seems to be Float32 for AudioUnits . Your stuff works great!

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing something unrelated to `AudioUnits` but I am using `AudioStreamBasicDescription` on iOS.  I was able to use float samples by specifying:

```
dstFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
```

The book [Learning Core Audio: A Hands-on Guide to Audio Programming for Mac and iOS](http://books.google.com/books?id=goPI1hbU6z4C&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat%20ios&source=bl&ots=DjP8jwKgaA&sig=Be1h1JBLZtstoA4wpgpmHtwPb-w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rWONUp_oNYKtiQKbqIDgAQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat%20ios&f=false) was helpful for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is supported.

The problem is you must also set `kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved` on `mFormatFlags`. If you don't do this when setting `kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat`, you will get a format error.

So, you want to do something like this when preparing your `AudioStreamBasicDescription`:

```
streamDescription.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | 
                                 kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
```

As for why iOS requires this, I'm not sure - I only stumbled across it via trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

From the Core Audio docs:

```
kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat
  Set for floating point, clear for integer.
  Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.
  Declared in CoreAudioTypes.h.
```

I don't know enough about your stream to comment on its [in]correctness.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain an interleaved float RemoteIO with the following ASBD setup:

```
// STEREO_CHANNEL = 2, defaultSampleRate = 44100
AudioStreamBasicDescription const audioDescription = {
                    .mSampleRate        = defaultSampleRate,
                    .mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
                    .mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat,
                    .mBytesPerPacket    = STEREO_CHANNEL * sizeof(float),
                    .mFramesPerPacket   = 1,
                    .mBytesPerFrame     = STEREO_CHANNEL * sizeof(float),
                    .mChannelsPerFrame  = STEREO_CHANNEL,
                    .mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * sizeof(float),
                    .mReserved          = 0
                };
```

This worked for me.